# Better Gaussian Elimination for solving $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

We know that Gaussian Elimination is very popular method to resolve $Ax=b$. Does anyone know better method than Gaussian Elimination in term of time complexity? Second question,if I assume that A is sparse matrix. Has any method faster than Gaussian Elimination. Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

How fast you can solve a linear system depends on how fast you can multiply matrices.

Even though there are in theoretically faster algorithms, the fastest algorithm I've heard is in use is *Strassen's algorithm* (or closely related algorithms). Strassen's algorithm is based on a technique for multiplication of $2 \times 2$-matrices which uses 7 multiplications instead of 8, which might seem trivial, but once you scale it up you get a significant improvement. The complexity of Strassen's algorithm is $O(n^{2.8074})$.

Indeed, the paper where Strassen presented this algorithm was named *Gaussian Elimination is not Optimal*, published in 1968. The algorithm for faster matrix multiplication was just a step on the way to constructing a faster method for constructing the inverse of a matrix, showing that it can be done with $< 5.64 n^{\log 7}$ arithmetic operations. Strassen also writes that *"Similar results hold for solving a system of linear equations..."* but does not provide details. I think the paper is freely available.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is equivalent to computing the inverse of matrix which is clearly enough to solve a linear system.  In the worst case, Gaussian elimination takes $O(n^3)$ time.  On the other hand, the best algorithm currently known for matrix multiplication takes $O(n^{2.3728639 \ldots})$ time.

There is also an algorithm based on gradient descent that is fast when the condition number (the ratio of the largest and smallest singular values) of the matrix is in a certian range.

As for your question about sparsity, if a matrix is $k$-sparse, there is a natural $O(n^2 k)$ time algorithm and I imagine better results are known as well.

Comment: Could you give me the name of this algorithm?

Comment: Which algorithm?

Comment: The algorithm make fast invert matrix $O(n^{2.3728639}…)$

Comment: It's called Le Gall's algorithm.